# Regex for taking particular string under particular heading

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Heading_1:
   content1: some value
   content1: some value
   ...
   ...
Heading_2:
  content_1: some value
  content_2: some value
  ....

Heading_x:
  content_1: some value
  ....
  content_x: some value
  ...

Heading_n:
  ........
  ........
```

I want to find "some value" of content_x under heading_x using regular expression.
I did like this:

```
"((?=heading_x:)([\\w\\W\n\\s+]content_x:\\s+(.*)\n))"
```

but it's giving null. Please tell me where it went wrong.

Comment: We could help if you give us *exact input and output*.

Comment: Input is exactly like in the image(with next lines and spaces as such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?s)Heading_x:.*?content_x:\s*([^\n]*)
```

Java regex would be,

```
(?s)Heading_x:.*?content_x:\\s*([^\\n]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/1)

Get the value of `content_x` from group index 1.

Comment: what if content_x has more than 1 value. Like content_x:some_value1   content_x:some_value2

Answer (score 1):

```
Heading_x:((?!Heading_\d+:)[\s\S])*? content_x.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DqIkP3PWRLznqt5H)

Comment: Tim, Thanks for sharing this link